# multiple custom error message support per field by using parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to validate a simple form using parsley.js and I am very beginner on parsley.js.I would like to show multiple error messages in one custom validation method using window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator() method.So I have tried out in my way.

Simple html form I have created

```html
<html>
 <head>Custom Validation Parsley
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parsley.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/my-validator-parsley.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
     
      <p>
        <label for="cemail">E-Mail with custom method (required)</label>
        <input id="cemail" name="checkEmail" data-parsley-checkEmail>
      </p>
     
     
      <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
  $("#commentForm").parsley();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the javascript file that is included the custom validation method

```js
var errorMsg = "";
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('checkEmail', function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    if (value == "") {

      errorMsg = "this field must not be empty";

      return false;
    } else {
      var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

      if (!regex.test(value)) {

        errorMsg = "this field must be email ***";
        

      }
      return regex.test(value);
      window.ParsleyValidator.addMessage('en', 'checkEmail',
        errorMsg);
    }

  }, 32)
  //.addMessage('en','checkEmail',window.ParsleyValidator.catalog)
;
```

But It's not working for me.Can anyone give me advice on this and how to approach this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only assign one message per constraint in a given locale.

From http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/validator.html:

```
addMessage: function (locale, name, message) {
  if ('undefined' === typeof this.catalog[locale])
    this.catalog[locale] = {};

  this.catalog[locale][name.toLowerCase()] = message;

  return this;
},
```

Thus if you want multiple messages, define multiple validators.

Also,

- if you want a field to be required there's no need to check if it's empty; just  add `required` attribute to it (e.g. `<input ... required />`)
- Parsley is bundled with common validators (http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators) and "email" is one of them; to enable it add attribute `type="email"` to your input (e.g. `<input type="email"  required />`)

UPDATE:

From http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript:

> `window.ParsleyUI.updateError(parsleyInstance, name, message);`
>   Manually edit an error message.

Also, you can set the message from your validator function by directly assigning it to the `catalog` instead of using `addMessage()`(note that the name of the validator should be all lowercase):

```
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('checkEmail', function(value) {

    if (...)
        window.ParsleyValidator.catalog.en.checkemail = 'Some error message AAA';
    else
        window.ParsleyValidator.catalog.en.checkemail = 'Some error message BBB';

    return (...);

}, 32);
```

Comment: Thus I can simply add required and email by using parsley.But the exact purpose why I am doing this way is the form which will be created dynamically using handlebar.js and registry extensoin file and need to set the validations when the field is created in a form.This is Just I am making Proof of concept to show the support multiple error message per validator custom method can do by parsley.js.So can you please advice me Is this possible by parsley.js